# How to export a menu and blocks?

Tags: 8, navigation

I created a Superfish menu in a test installation of Drupal (8.5.4) and want to import it into another install (8.5.5).  How can I do this?

Is the navigation data stored in menu_link, menu_link_content, and menu_tree?  I tried importing these tables into my new install, but when I try to "Place Block" in Block Layout - I don't see the old menu showing up as a Superfish block.

I also tried using the [Menu Export module](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_export). But was unable to find the "Menu Export Configuration" page that they show in the image.

The new install is migrated from Drupal 7. So it lacks a config table.  Where is the config installed?  I think I need to copy the menu which is stored in a blob in the config table, but I don't know where to put it.

Note: The main question is "How can I export the menu"? To which the answer appears to be "Not possible." I'm still confused though as the menu information has to be stored somewhere. The other sub-questions are trying to get at pieces of the puzzle.

Comment: Ufff, that are many questions. Please try to narrow down your problem to one specific question. Otherwise this question simply is too broad to be answered in this site's Q&A style as it requires a lot of back-and-forth communication we can't and don't want to handle here.

Comment: Links are content I believe and not exportable out of the box. Menus themselves are exportable.

Comment: The main question is "How can I export the menu"?  To which the answer appears to be "Not possible."  I'm still confused though as the menu information has to be stored somewhere.

The other sub-questions are trying to get at pieces of the puzzle.

Answer (score 1):

Both menu link items and custom block content are treated as ***content*** within Drupal core. That's to say, they ***aren't covered*** by the configuration management system.

In instances where it make sense to have menu link items or custom block content stored in the configuration system, there are modules out there to assist with this:

- [Fixed block content](https://www.drupal.org/project/fixed_block_content): Provides a way of having permanent custom content blocks without broken instances if the block does not exist.
- [Config menu link](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_link_config): A drop-in replacement for core's Custom Menu Links module.

There many other options to store menu/block data into the config system so it's worth your time to explore other options to find the one that best matches your scenario (especially since Superfish seems to be a part of it).

Comment: If the menu items are content, how can I export and import them?

Comment: Drupal core won't let you (without trying to copy DB tables) The above example modules use the config management system to import/export.

Comment: I'm up for copying the tables.

Comment: Here is something I found - https://github.com/calbasi/migrate_menu - Not sure about the state of the solution though.